# Problematic Wireless connection manager in Kubuntu 9.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, kubuntu

I've recently upgraded my Kubuntu installation to 9.04 and somehow the wireless manager is not working any more. I believe it is the official bug mentioned in [this](http://www.itnewstoday.com/?p=293) article. Have any of you encountered this and have a solution? As a workaround I started using [WICD](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/), and I quite like it, but I would look at any solution involving the standard KDE manager.

Comment: Please could you expand on this a bit more. Is it all wireless networks or just WEP ones, or just hidden ones ?

Comment: Have you tried the GNOME network manager instead?

Comment: I'm kind of a KDE fan. I'm not a *real* linux guy and try to stick to KDE. And anything Gnome cannot work under it, right?

Comment: @Slavo: They're usually pretty good at working together - when you attempt to install it (may need an extra repo, but probably not) it'll just fetch all of it's own dependancies. The icon styling may be slightly off, but I've had no problems installing stuff from KDE onto a Xubuntu computer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have already read these:

[jaunty (9.04) relase notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/JauntyJackalope/ReleaseNotes#Kubuntu%20Network%20Management%20applet%20does%20not%20connect%20to%20WPA2%20networks)

Apart from the workarounds using wicd or nm-applet (which is the gnome frontend fornetwork-manager and has a much nicer UI if you ask me), you can also just reinstall the old qt3 knetworkmanager from the repositories.

If you feel a little adventurous you can also add the *kubuntu backports ppa* (just google it) to your sources.list (description on how to do that is on the ppa page) and upgrade to KDE 4.3, maybe that will solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue, I changed to a different driver and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same problem on a workstation. The [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-release-notes/+bug/339313) gives a few options e.g. installing an experimental update - but like you I've chosen wicd for now - I'll be watching for updates too.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing windows driver that might have come with the card using ndiswrapper. How to use ndiswrapper is written in my response to question at [hp 6716s, 6715b, and 6710s laptops on linux wireless problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/14504/hp-6716s-6715b-and-6710s-laptops-on-linux-wireless-problem)

Comment: not an option, sorry, just using wicd is much easier anyway.